# Hyperlink Image Figma

Tags: pdf, figma

Is there a way to hyperlink and image or text in Figma to be clickable when exported as a PDF? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tricky solution I came up with: Put text over the image that is the same size as image, hyper link it to desired link, put `opacity` of font at 0%. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder that you can self-accept your own answer if your issue is solved. That will also keep the question from bumping on the homepage regularly so users can focus on non-resolved issues  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Put a text box over it, command+k, paste link, make text transparent.

Comment: That's exactly what was mentioned in the other answer, please avoid repeating the same information. Check [answer] to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Like @user2980368 said, your only alternative is to put some text on top of your image, link it and make it transparent.

> Unfortunately, while you cannot directly link images in Figma, there
> is a workaround. The only way to add a link to an image in Figma would
> be to create a text layer on top of the image with a link, and make it
> transparent or only type spaces in it.

Source: https://8designers.com/blog/how-do-i-add-a-link-to-a-figma-image

Disclaimer: I wrote the article.